# Unable to set white borders to BasicCard with Actions on Google

Tags: actions-on-google

I've deployed an action (only in Indonesian language) that need to display a basic card with white borders. The `imageDisplayOptions` is set to `WHITE` according to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/ImageDisplayOptions) (and also [here](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/modules/actionssdk_api_v2.html#googleactionsv2uielementsbasiccardimagedisplayoptions)). The configuration is confirmed in JSON response from logs. But the UI is still displaying gray borders (see screenshot below).

Am I missing something that has changed in AoG for this?

App directory listing (only supporting Indonesian language): https://assistant.google.com/services/a/uid/000000a72f6604c0?hl=id&source=web

### JSON response payload from Firebase logs

[image: JSON payload from logs]

### Application screenshot

[image: Application screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that isn't working for some reason, you might try changing the default background color for the cards in the Actions on Google Console [hereish](https://actions-console.corp.google.com/u/0/)

[image: AoG Console]

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be a good solution for now. Since the client isn't the theme colors for general purpose. I filed an issue with the AoG team and it's in process.